# python class variables not getting changed for all the instances?

Tags: python-2.7

I realized Python class variables have same memory location for all the instances, however I am not getting why changing the class variable from one of the instance don't affect other instances and class itself? Please see following code below:

```
class (object):
    name = 'Donald '
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 4
c = Sam()
z = Sam()
print hex(id(c.name)), hex(id(z.name)), hex(id(Sam.name))
print c.name, z.name

c.name = 'Trump'
print c.name, z.name, US_President.name
print hex(id(c.name)), hex(id(z.name)), hex(id(US_President.name))

US_President.name = 'Obama'
print c.name, z.name, US_President.name


Output:
0x7f227776a930 0x7f227776a930 0x7f227776a930
Donald Donald
Trump Donald Donald
0x7f227776a420 0x7f227776a930 0x7f227776a930
Trump Obama Obama
```

Can somebody please explain this behavior. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you assign to an attribute of an instance, that name becomes an instance variable.  If there was a class variable of the same name, it becomes hidden in that particular instance, but is still accessible in other instances of the class.  If you want to modify a class variable, you have to assign it on the class, not an instance.